# texshade in overleaf produces errors that I don't understand

Tags: errors

I`m trying to visualize a stretch of a protein with texshade. I would like to only show residues 400 to 600, shade some parts and put annotated braces above and below, but I get the entire sequence, some random characters before it, and depending on the order of the commands, no pdf.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{texshade} 

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{protein.fasta}
>sp|P42566|EPS15_HUMAN Epidermal growth factor receptor substrate 15 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=EPS15 PE=1 SV=2
MAAAAQLSLTQLSSGNPVYEKYYRQVDTGNTGRVLASDAAAFLKKSGLPDLILGKIWDLA
DTDGKGILNKQEFFVALRLVACAQNGLEVSLSSLNLAVPPPRFHDTSSPLLISGTSAAEL
PWAVKPEDKAKYDAIFDSLSPVNGFLSGDKVKPVLLNSKLPVDILGRVWELSDIDHDGML
DRDEFAVAMFLVYCALEKEPVPMSLPPALVPPSKRKTWVVSPAEKAKYDEIFLKTDKDMD
GFVSGLEVREIFLKTGLPSTLLAHIWSLCDTKDCGKLSKDQFALAFHLISQKLIKGIDPP
HVLTPEMIPPSDRASLQKNIIGSSPVADFSAIKELDTLNNEIVDLQREKNNVEQDLKEKE
DTIKQRTSEVQDLQDEVQRENTNLQKLQAQKQQVQELLDELDEQKAQLEEQLKEVRKKCA
EEAQLISSLKAELTSQESQISTYEEELAKAREELSRLQQETAELEESVESGKAQLEPLQQ
HLQDSQQEISSMQMKLMEMKDLENHNSQLNWCSSPHSILVNGATDYCSLSTSSSETANLN
EHVEGQSNLESEPIHQESPARSSPELLPSGVTDENEVTTAVTEKVCSELDNNRHSKEEDP
FNVDSSSLTGPVADTNLDFFQSDPFVGSDPFKDDPFGKIDPFGGDPFKGSDPFASDCFFR
QSTDPFATSSTDPFSAANNSSITSVETLKHNDPFAPGGTVVAASDSATDPFASVFGNESF
GGGFADFSTLSKVNNEDPFRSATSSSVSNVVITKNVFEETSVKSEDEPPALPPKIGTPTR
PCPLPPGKRSINKLDSPDPFKLNDPFQPFPGNDSPKEKDPEIFCDPFTSATTTTNKEADP
SNFANFSAYPSEEDMIEWAKRESEREEEQRLARLNQQEQEDLELAIALSKSEISEA
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{texshade}{protein.fasta}
\hideconsensus
\hidenames
\showruler
\residuesperline{50}
\setdomain{1}{400..600}
\feature{top}{1}{458..463}{brace}{cdk}
\tintblock{1}{458..463}
\end{texshade}

\end{document}
```

[This](https://www.overleaf.com/6534718236bxrrwwydgqnr) is the overleaf.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Could you make this a bit more complete by showing us how you're using the code?  Ideally by making this a 15 line example that you think should be complete, even if it has the errors that you're seeing.  (And in general, only the first error is useful.  After that, TeX starts guessing at what you meant.)

Comment: It gives the same error using TL19-23.

Comment: When I leave out 
```
\residuesperline{50}
```
it at least produces a pdf.

Comment: I've found this remark on the texshade ctan.org site. I don't know if it applies to the package version used by overleaf:
"Fix for people who are getting errors while using TEXshade v1.26:
1. Locate the file texshade.sty on your system. This may vary based on how you installed LATEX.
2. Find the line below (should be line 156 in v1.26 released on 2021/04/01):
\xdef\par@{\expandafter\string\par}
3. Replace it with these two lines:
\xdef\par@{\par}
\xdef\par@{\expandafter\string\par@}
Should work now."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice people at overleaf helped:

> The current version of texshade installed on Overleaf would indeed have this error. If you upload the latest version of texshade.sty to your project (also attached), then the compilation should complete without errors.
> When we upgrade to TeX Live 2023 later this year, texshade will also be upgraded on the server.

I've included the file in the [updated MWE](https://de.overleaf.com/read/ykznfjgybrmc).

The other problem was caused by missing options

```
{1}{top}
```

in *\showruler*.

Comment: Could you include the MWE here?

Comment: The overleaf link above has the texshade.sty. Is there a way to include files here? It's really long so I thought its a bad idea to just put it in as text

Comment: Anyone with TeX installed should be able to locate the file at `kpsewhich texshade.sty`.  If they don't have TeX installed, then it would be more complicated to get the updated file.  If that's that only change (and including the options to `\showruler`), then I agree that we probably don't want to post it here.